# Extract data from structured syslog

Tags: regex, awk, syslog

I have about 30k structured syslog messages in the following format:

> `<14>1 2015-03-10T15:08:06.049Z ams99-fwc-a15-3600-01 RT_FLOW - RT_FLOW_SESSION_CREATE [junos@2636.1.1.1.2.34 source-address="172.17.6.11" source-port="123" destination-address="10.78.0.13" destination-port="123" service-name="junos-ntp" nat-source-address="172.17.6.11" nat-source-port="123" nat-destination-address="10.78.0.13" nat-destination-port="123" src-nat-rule-name="None" dst-nat-rule-name="None" protocol-id="17" policy-name="ntp-access" source-zone-name="network-management" destination-zone-name="wan" session-id-32="140046548" username="N/A" roles="N/A" packet-incoming-interface="reth0.990" application="UNKNOWN" nested-application="UNKNOWN" encrypted="UNKNOWN"]`

I need to extract only the data in between within inverted comas "...."
So to get something like:

```
172.17.6.11 123 10.78.0.13  123 junos-ntp 172.17.6.11   123     10.78.0.13  123     None    None    17
```

I also need  to replace the last octet of all IP addresses with 0. So it can get to:

```
172.17.6.0  123 10.78.0.0   123 junos-ntp
```

Can you please advise. I managed to do it with awk , using first " and then "." as a field separator, but  I wonder if you can help me to do it in a more efficient and intelligent way.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's better to use `sed` for that:

**1. part - Extracting values between double quotes**

```
sed -r 's/[^"]*"([^"]+)"[^"]*/ \1 /g' /var/log/syslog
```

*Explanation:*

I'm using the substitute command `s`. The search pattern searches for one or more non `"` characters until it reaches a `"`. The following non `"` characters until the next `"` will get captured into capturing group `1`. After the closing `"` it matches the following non `"` characters (This is important at the end of the line).

The replacement pattern just outputs the contents of capturing group `1` - wrapped in whitespace - and throws the remaining match away.

Using the `g` option tells sed to apply the `s` command multiple times per line.

---

**2. part - Replacing the last octet of the IP by `0`s**

You can use the following simple command to match a regex. Note that it would even match strings like `999.999.999.999` while this isn't an IP. However the regex should be good enough for an example:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}(\.([0-9]{1,3}){2})\.([0-9]+))\.[0-9]+/\1.0/g' /var/log/syslog
```

*Explanation:*

I'm using the `s` command again. The search pattern captures sequences of 1 to 3 numbers concatened with a dot and stores them in capturing group `1`. After that and outside of the capturing group the fourth part of the IP gets matched.

In the replacement pattern the content of capturing group `1` is printed and the `.0` gets added.

The `g` option is used to replace all IPs in the line.

**Note:** The pattern above works for IPv4 addresses only.

---

**Putting it together**

You can simply separate multiple sed commands by `;`:

```
sed -r 's/[^"]*"([^"]+)"[^"]*/ \1 /g;s/([0-9]{1,3}(\.([0-9]{1,3}){2})\.([0-9]+))\.[0-9]+/\1.0/g' /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Exactly what I needed and because of being so well explained, I can modify and apply it to similar tasks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy hacking! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1)?OFS:ORS)}' file
172.17.6.11 123 10.78.0.13 123 junos-ntp 172.17.6.11 123 10.78.0.13 123 None None 17 ntp-access network-management wan 140046548 N/A N/A reth0.990 UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
```

and with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -F'"' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { $i=gensub(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.).*/,"\\10","",$i); printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1)?OFS:ORS) } }' file
172.17.6.0 123 10.78.0.0 123 junos-ntp 172.17.6.0 123 10.78.0.0 123 None None 17 ntp-access network-management wan 140046548 N/A N/A reth0.990 UNKNOWN UNKNOWN UNKNOWN
```